# Was the French philosopher Pierre Bayle a Calvinist believer or an atheist?

Tags: 17th-century, philosophy, individuals

European Enlightenment: The 17th century's most read philosopher produced sharp and honest literature. Yet until today the question seems to be unanswered where he really belonged (Bayle enigma).

Answer (score 2):

Wiki says he [professed himself to be a Protestant.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Bayle)

Do you have reason to doubt this? And why would the only alternative to a Calvinist Protestant be for him to be an atheist, when there were many other Christian sects and denominations?

Comment: Well, there have been times when I had reason to doubt Wikipedia content. In this case they correctly cite Bayle as a "self-pronounced Protestant". The challenge here is less Wikipedia, but more the self-conception of this great philosopher. Anyway, I agree with you that there were many more options of Christian existence than only Calvinism. Thanks Guy.

Answer (score 1):

The [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](http://plato.stanford.edu/) states that Bayle was considered to be a [skeptic in many ways](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/bayle/#BaySke). He was engaged in theological debate his whole life, but at a time when atheists were extraordinarily rare. As a son of a priest I think it's hard to believe he was an outright atheist, but he was certainly not a devout believer. He seems to be a person that was a little ahead of his time.

Comment: The excellent SEP essay (thanks ihtkwot!) makes clear that we can only assume where Bayle personally stood. According to his available publications I have a tendency to say that he himself vacillated all his life between the two poles of divine experience and doubtful skepticism. In so far, I agree with ihtkwot that Bayle was ahead of his time.